# Selenium Webdriver : How to run testNG.xml file in Terminal (in MAC)?

Tags: java, xml, maven, selenium, testng

I have created a Maven-testNG project in MAC system. I have created a testSuite and now i want to run testNG.xml file using **Terminal**. Is there any way to run this xml file?

[image]

**testNG.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="2">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.Live.testcase.TC0001_Signup" />
            <class name="com.Live.testcase.TC0002_SoleProprietorship" />
            <class name="com.Live.testcase.TC0003_Login" />
            <class name="com.Live.testcase.TC0004_ForgotPassword" />
            <class name="com.Live.testcase.TC0005_LLC" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.learnautomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.learnautomation.selenium</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <suitXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suitXmlFile>
        <skipTests> false </skipTests>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>

                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>


                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jexcelapi/jxl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Note:** I have seen many options on internet. Mostly about running code through **command line (windows machine)** and few suggestions those are not maven project means simple project, go to the library section and run the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said my testng file is in build folder so i have to give path in  `<suiteXmlFile>build/${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>`

Done some changes in **Pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>build/${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

command to run:

$ cd path/to/your/project

$ `mvn test -DsuiteFile=testng.xml`

or

$`mvn clean test -DsuiteFile=testng.xml`

**Reference youtube link:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQCyVy-g1e8&t=436s

---

**Note:**

If your `testng.xml` file does not belong to any folder and you just want to call `testng.xml` everytime, no other xml file from project.

simply put `<suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>`
Run command

$ cd path/to/your/project

$ `mvn test`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can run the testng.xml file from terminal. You should have `maven` installed in your machine. Following command would help.

```
$ brew install maven
```

After that you can simply use `mvn` command to execute maven goals in your project. Following command would execute your testng.xml file if you had configured the Pom.xml file accordingly

```
$ cd path/to/your/project
$ mvn test
```

Comment: `mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=YourTestSuiteFileName` would be the appropriate command.

Comment: Yes. But Pom.xml already has `<suitXmlFile>` tag. So not necessary to mention in the command again.

Comment: 1. `mvn clean install`
2. `mvn test`
any thing should work. But maven should be installed and .m2 path should be set

Comment: showing error if i use mvn clean install.

https://prnt.sc/pw8894

showing error if i use mvn test

https://prnt.sc/pw88qh

Comment: You have set `<suiteXmlFile>` set to src/main/resources/testng.xml. Make sure that your xml file is here and try again.

Comment: Can you check what happens if you will remove whole `<configuration>` section and then run `mvn test` from you project directory?

Comment: omeniq - it doesn't throw any error but testng.xml doesn't run as well https://prnt.sc/pwc83t